# Render django formset forms inside another loop (Other item loop) inside table)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model formset for entering `quantity field` for `SaleInvoice model`. I pass the `SaleInvoiceItems` to django template and use a loop to render them in a table. What I want is to render the individual forms in a formset along with the items inside the table.

the `tbody` of My Template looks like this

```
  <tbody style="background-color: #ffffff;">
   {{formset.management_form}}
    {% for item in line_item %}
     <tr>
      <td>{{item.line_number}}</td>
      <td>{{item.item.item_description}}</td>
      <td>{{item.item.item_uom}}</td>
      <td>{{item.sale_price}}</td>
      <td>{{item.order_quantity}}</td>      

->    <td>Here I want to render a form field from the formset</td>
      
      <td><input disabled type="text" name="" value=""></td>
      <td>{{item.tax.tax_value}}</td>
      <td><input disabled type="text" name="" value=""></td>
      <td><input disabled type="text" name="" value=""></td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
```

view

```
class CreateSaleOrderInvoiceItem(FormView):
    model = SaleOrderInvoiceItem
    form_class = SaleOrderInvoiceItemForm
    template_name = 'saleorderinvoicesapp/createsaleorderinvoiceitem.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        # id_selected_item = self.request.session.pop('so_invoice_selected_item')
        id_selected_item = self.request.session['so_invoice_selected_item']
        line_item = SaleOrderItem.objects.filter(id__in=id_selected_item)
        sale_order = line_item.first().sale_order
        no_of_items = len(id_selected_item)
        formdata={
            'form-TOTAL_FORMS': no_of_items,
            'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
            'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
        }
        item_formset = SaleOrderInvoiceItemFormset(formdata)
        
        invoice_form = CreateSaleOrderInvoiceForm()
        context['invoice_form'] = invoice_form
        context['formset'] = item_formset
        context['line_item'] = line_item
        context['sale_order'] = sale_order
        context['buyer'] = sale_order.buyer
        context['project'] = sale_order.project

        return context
        
        def get_success_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
            return reverse('saleorderinvoicesApp:NewSaleOrderInvoice')
```

model

```
class SaleOrderInvoice(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    sale_order = models.ForeignKey(SaleOrder, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=56, unique=True)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    tax_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number

class SaleOrderInvoiceItem(models.Model):
    sale_order_invoice = models.ForeignKey(SaleOrderInvoice, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    item = models.ForeignKey(SaleOrderItem, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bill_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=4)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2)
    tax_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

form

```
class CreateSaleOrderInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SaleOrderInvoice
        fields = (
            'invoice_number',
            'invoice_date',
        )
        widgets={
                'invoice_number':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                'invoice_date':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date'}),
        }

class SaleOrderInvoiceItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # prefix='InvoiceItemForm'
        model = SaleOrderInvoiceItem
        fields = ('bill_quantity',)
        widgets={
            'bill_quantity':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm'})
        }

SaleOrderInvoiceItemFormset = modelformset_factory(
    SaleOrderInvoiceItem,
    form = SaleOrderInvoiceItemForm
)
```

Is it possible to render forms in a formset inside another loop?
One way of doing this is to append the individual form to the `line_item` list in the `context` dictionary, but it seems like a non-standard way of doing this also it doesn't updates the form with POST data (if the form is invalid), and I believe there must be some standard way of doing this.

Comment: please add your view, model, form,url

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have added the view, model and form as you asked